# Migrating Paperclip database to Active Storage Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip, rails-activestorage

We are in the process of migrating paperclip to active storage.But we want to move Paperclip storage from database to Active Storage Amazon S3. Can anyone point me to a documentation for this? I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this article](https://medium.com/sortlist-engineering/migrating-from-paperclip-to-activestorage-a-different-approach-4bffa2260e17) can help you. Code is missing due to Github username update but the main idea is there.

Or simply the [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/MIGRATING.md) of Paperclip. As you wish.